# How To read delta parquet multiple files incremental manner

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I have requirement is to read parquet delta files which is multiple files in single folder, actually we are trying read all the files under delta table folder in ADLS location.

The requirement is, when we load data in first time, we have to read all the files and load in spark table. the second time onwards, we would like to read the delta parquet format files to read incremental files or latest changes files using databricks pyspark notebook.

```
df= spark.table("deltaTable.table")
```

above code read all the data under above path but we want read incremental data also.

Could you please help us any samples.

thanks

Comment: have you tried any approach?add your error details.

Comment: this is full load data " df= spark.table("deltaTable.table") " code, i want to read incremental read files data

Comment: How that table is changed? If you want to read it as stream it should be append only table (so not deletes or updates). Other options is to turn on CDC and read CDC events from it.

Comment: You can check options here: https://docs.databricks.com/structured-streaming/delta-lake.html

Answer (score 0):

The below code in PySpark that will perform an incremental load for two Delta tables named "**employee_table**" and "**department_table**".

Here is the initial load for the "**employee_table**" and "**department_table**".

[image]

[image]

[image]

The Below is the Initial load files for 2 tables.
[image]

As you said you read all the files under delta table folder in ADLS location.
As an example I have *INSERT and UPDATE operations as part of the incremental load process.

The below is code doing the incremental load and writing the output to the ADLS file path as parquet.

```
new_employees_data = [("Alice Johnson", 29, "Data Engineer"),
                      ("Michael Smith", 32, "Data Analyst")]
new_departments_data = [("Quality Assurance", "Chicago")]
updated_employee_data = [("John Doe", 31, "Lead Software Engineer")]
updated_department_data = [("Engineering", "San Francisco")]
new_employees_df = spark.createDataFrame(new_employees_data, ["name", "age", "designation"])
new_departments_df = spark.createDataFrame(new_departments_data, ["department", "location"])
updated_employee_df = spark.createDataFrame(updated_employee_data, ["name", "age", "designation"])
updated_department_df = spark.createDataFrame(updated_department_data, ["department", "location"])
output_path = "abfss://folder1@synapseadlsgen2july23.dfs.core.windows.net/From_Databricks_delta_new/Incremental_file/"
"employees" table.
new_employees_df = new_employees_df.withColumn("operation", lit("insert"))
updated_employee_df = updated_employee_df.withColumn("operation", lit("update"))
employees_incremental_data = new_employees_df.union(updated_employee_df)
employees_incremental_data.write \
    .format("parquet") \
    .mode("append") \
    .save(output_path + "employees")
"departments" table.
new_departments_df = new_departments_df.withColumn("operation", lit("insert"))
updated_department_df = updated_department_df.withColumn("operation", lit("update"))
departments_incremental_data = new_departments_df.union(updated_department_df)
departments_incremental_data.write \
    .format("parquet") \
    .mode("append") \
    .save(output_path + "departments")
```

- For the "employees" table, two DataFrames are created: new_employees_df for new employees and updated_employee_df for updated employee information.
- For the "departments" table, two DataFrames are created new_departments_df for new departments and updated_department_df for updated department information.
- An "operation" column is added to each DataFrame to indicate whether a record is an "insert" or an "update".

**Reading the incremental data from ADLS as parquet and writing to DELTA tables in databricks:**

- The code reads Parquet files from Azure Data Lake Storage (ADLS) into Spark DataFrames, and then register those DataFrames as Delta tables.
- Delta is the extension of Parquet files that provides additional features like **ACID** transactions, schema evolution, and more.
- The DataFrames are written back to the store in Delta format using the write method.

These Delta tables can be queried using SQL or Spark DataFrame API and will benefit from Delta's ACID properties.

[image]

```
input_path = "abfss://folder1@synapseadlsgen2july23.dfs.core.windows.net/From_Databricks_delta_new/Incremental_file/"
employees_df = spark.read.format("parquet").load(input_path + "employees")
departments_df = spark.read.format("parquet").load(input_path + "departments")
employees_df.write \
    .format("delta") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .saveAsTable("employees")
departments_df.write \
    .format("delta") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .saveAsTable("departments")
```

[image]

Comment: we are not writing back to any table or storage, we would like to read delta table from adls location with incremental read and pass the details to APIs. in this case normal spark.table("table path") read all the multiples for full load but i want to load first time full load and second time only changes files only read and pass the details to APIs.

Comment: @DeveloperKE I understand you are not writing back to ADLS. in the solution I have used it as an example. let me try this spark.table("table path") and update the solution

Comment: please try and give your examples, it will be helpful.